# Telebot. Ожидание ответа и сохранение переменных

Tags: python, telebot

Пишу бота с помощью telebot и вот проблема.
Кусочек кода:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    if (message.text == 'Посчитать'):
```

Дальше мне нужно, чтобы в этом IF пользователь ввёл 2 числа в разных сообщениях и я мог выполнить с ними математические операции. Что нужно сделать? Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: прочитать документацию к библиотеке, там даже примеры есть :)

Answer (score 1):

У telebot есть функция register_next_step_handler:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def handle_text(message):
    if (message.text == 'Посчитать'):
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, f_num)
@bot.message_handler()
def f_num(msg):
    first_number = msg.text
    #bot.register_next_step_handler(все что в первой функции)
```

А вообще более подробное объяснение с примерами есть в документации, есть видео на YouTube и тд. Документация по теме: https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html